# python nested loop with if statement

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested

I have a question about nested loops in python. I want the code to loop through all `i in extracting(a).make_all_list` and if it is matched with `e['Kummi']` then print something,. If it cannot find any match for `e['Kummi']`, print that `e['Kummi']`. However, I believe what the code below does is whenever the `e['kummi]` is not matched, it will print out, even though later in the search it will find a match for that `e['kummi']`

```
for e in kummi:
    #b=' '.join(e)
    #re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', b)
    for i in extracting(a).make_all_list():
        if (e.split(' ',l)[0] in i['Käyttönimi'])==True & (e.split(' ',l)[l] in i['Käyttönimi'])==True:
            print(e + ' ' + i['Sähköposti'] + ' ' + i['Käyttönimi'])
        else:
            print(e + ' not found')
```

Comment: You are using the `bitwise` operator `&` in the `if` condition. Use `and`.

Comment: Also `xyzzy == True` is the same and simply: `xyzzy`

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment, I have tried with writing the code, but there is some problem about indent that I cannot find out how to fix. Besides, even though you get my code you cannot run it because you do not have data which I am not allowed to share

Comment: Hi, I think the bitwise operator or problem with True does not help. Because what I want is it go through all the extracting(a).make_all_list() first, and if it does not found anything, it execute the else statement.

Comment: Replace image by code. Highlight inline code.

Comment: Indent your code by selecting it, and pressing `{ }` icon in the StackOverflow editor. This will put 4 spaces before each line, so that it gets formatted as code. Concerning the data which you cannot share: provide fake data instead.